Unable to use the "npm run dev" command,it gives error on running the command in Terminal
Terminal with npm error
These are the error I'm Getting
npm error Missing script: "dev"
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts,run:
npm error npm run
I have installed all the required modules and dependencies also npm install and all done.While working with other project the command"npm run dev" was working fine,but it is not working now?what can be the possible reason and how can I resolve it
It should have started the new  next js project in the browser.But now it shows Error
These are the error I'm Getting
npm error Missing script: "dev"
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts,run:
npm error npm r
un

Is there a script called dev in your package.json? "scripts": { "dev": "..." }?

can you past you package.json file ?

Remember that the commands that you execute with "npm run" are the ones that are inside the package.json file in your project. The error is telling you that the "dev" command is no present in the "scripts" inside the package.json.
Whatever the command is that you need to execute to run your application, you must add it there. For example, in a NextJS application, it looks like this:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  ...
}

Also, make sure to run the command in the root folder of your project, the one where the package.json file is present.
